# Как установить признак "Только чтение" в хелпере MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

**Asp.net, mvc** - Делаю вьюху для создания новой модели:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "ID")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
```

Возникло 2 вопроса:

1. Собственно как установить поле Edit в "только чтение"? пробовал `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new {disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly"})` - не помогает.
2. Как задать представление для пустого id в этом поле? сейчас для пустого id выводится "0" - хотелось бы заменить на пустую строку, или на текстовое сообщение.

Comment: так как Id - `int` у него нет _пустого_ значение, по умолчанию его значение `0`, что собственно и выводится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model string
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: Благодарю, с "только чтением" все решилось. А что на счет 2го вопроса?

Comment: JavaScript-ом спрячь и все.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

2.

```
@{Model.Id == default(int) ? string.Empty : Model.Id}
```